# Apply a continue statement that will skip printing the first 10 numerical values of the involved variable for the program

Tags: java, variables, numbers

I need to apply a continue statement that will skip printing the first  10  values.

I already have my code

```
public class numbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         for (int number=1; number <= 99; number++){

             if (number % 2 == 0)
                 System.out.print(number + " " );

                        System.out.println();
             }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Then do some research on "if" and "continue", instead of dumping something that could also be just the template you got as starter for your homework. Hint: you *learn* programming by actively trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have another counter

```
    int count = 0;
    for (int number=1; number <= 50; number++){

        if (number % 2 == 0 && count++ >= 10)
        {
            System.out.print(number + " " );
            System.out.println();
        }
   }
```

or if you want to use a continue

```
    int count = 0;
    for (int number=1; number <= 50; number++){

        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (count++ < 10)
                   continue;

            System.out.print(number + " " );
            System.out.println();
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int counter = 0;
     for (int number = 1; number <= 50; number++) {
         if (number % 2 == 0) {
             counter++;
             if (counter <= 10) {
                 continue;
             }
             System.out.println(number + " " );
         }
     }
}
```

With Java 8 `Stream`s it can be written more elegantly:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1,50).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).skip(10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: He is a newbie who asks to use *continue* because his assignment tells him to do so. Your answer doesn't address that all. And throwing a stream at a person unable to write down "continue" ... seriously?

Comment: Well, what I read said *I need to apply a continue statement*.